# Unable to open dev tools in Windows Application

Tags: windows, maui, maui-blazor, .net-maui, maui-windows

I had been working with Maui for the last couple of months. I had been using Dev tools (ctrl + shift +j) to see the design of the application. And made some changes accordingly. But now it's not working in 17.2.0 Preview 4. Is anything Changed or do we have to enable anything.

Dev Tools helps a lot in UI/ designing Applications.

Please let me know if anything has changed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an existing project this might happen. We have updated the new templates with this: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/blob/main/src/Templates/src/templates/maui-blazor/MauiProgram.cs#L21

If you want to enable the Dev Tools now, you need to explicitly do that in your `MauiProgram.cs`

```cs
#if DEBUG
        builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
#endif
```